# Return most popular facilities from booking?

Tags: python, python-3.x, booking.com-api

How to print most popular facilities from booking?

Ex:

[image: most popular facilities]

I tried this code:

```
for j in search(query, tld="co.in", num=1, stop=1):
    print(j)
    r = requests.get(j)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
    answ = soup.find("div", {"id":"hp_desc_important_facilities clearfix hp_desc_important_facilities--bui"}).text
    print(answ)
```

But nothing shown!

Any kind of help please?

Comment: Are we supposed to guess the HTML by looking at a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

I solve this by:

```
 answ = soup.find("div", {"class":"hp_desc_important_facilities clearfix hp_desc_important_facilities--bui"}).text
    print(answ)
```